# What is correct way to store information in python

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, class

I want to ask what is correct way to store information in python. Is it ok to store numbers in class (most of them integers) like this? Or some other way is better, more optimized.

```
class Eclass:
    def __init__(self, name, pre=None, suf=None, t=None, g=None, subg=None, p=0, a=0, m=0, v=0,
                 ast=0, d=0, bd=0, bhc=0, cc=0, bc=0, bhp=0, bmp=0, hpr=0, mr=0, br=0, pr=0,
                 sr=0, fr=0, er=0, ar=0, wr=0, ar=0, dr=0, vr=0, bar=0, lbr=0, lpr=0, lsr=0,
                 lfr=0, ler=0, lar=0, lwr=0, lare=0, ldr=0, lvr=0, lear=0, sl=0, sm=0, mr=0,
                 rr=0, td=0):
        self.name = name
        self.pre = pre
        self.suf = suf
        self.t = t
        self.g = g
        self.subg = subg
        self.oi = name
        self.p = p
        self.a = a
        self.m = m
        self.v = v
        self.ast = ast
        self.d = d
        self.bd = bd
        self.bhc = bhc
        self.cc = cc
        self.bc = bc
        self.bhp = bhp
        self.bmp = bmp
        self.hpr = hpr
        self.mr = mr

        self.br = br
        self.pr = pr
        self.sr = sr
        self.fr = fr
        self.er = er
        self.ar = ar
        self.wr = wr
        self.ar = ar
        self.dr = dr
        self.vr = vr
        self.bar = bar

        self.lbr = lbr
        self.lpr = lpr
        self.lsl = lsr
        self.lfi = lfr
        self.lea = lea
        self.lai = lai
        self.lwa = lwa
        self.lae = lar
        self.ldi = ldr
        self.lvo = lvr
        self.lear = lear

        self.sl = sl
        self.sm = sm

        self.mr = mr
        self.rr = rr
        self.td = td

        self.tags = []

    def add_tags(self, *args):
        for element in args:
            self.tags.append(element)
```

All of this is used in other functions that work with this class.

Comment: You should use a structure like a dictionary or list. And, please, use more descriptive names for your attributes.

Comment: This will certainly work, but it may be hard to work with - it requires a lot of typing, and a lot of chances to make mistakes. Look into dictionaries, or Pandas dataframes for more complex tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary would be appropriate for this.

```
dic1 = dict(pre=None, suf=None, t=None, g=None, subg=None, p=0, a=0, m=0, v=0, ast=0)
dic1['lwa'] = 0
dic2 = {'a': 0, 'suf': None, 'pre': None, 'g': None, 'ast': 0, 'm': 0, 'p': 0, 'subg': None, 't': None, 'v': 0, 'lwa': 0}

print (dic1)
print (dic2)
print (dic1['t'])
print (dic2['lwa'])
print (dic1 == dic2)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'suf': None, 'pre': None, 'g': None, 'ast': 0, 'm': 0, 'p': 0, 'subg': None, 't': None, 'v': 0, 'lwa': 0}
{'pre': None, 'ast': 0, 'subg': None, 'a': 0, 'suf': None, 'g': None, 'm': 0, 'p': 0, 't': None, 'v': 0, 'lwa': 0}
None
0
True
```

Comment: [NamedTuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) is another option. Much lower memory usage compared to a dictionary if you have a lot of values.